# Swift FFT - Complex split issue

Tags: ios, swift, signal-processing, fft, frequency

I am trying to perform **FFT** on an **audio file** to find frequency using the Accelerate framework. I have adapted code (probably wrong) from this question: [Spectrogram from AVAudioPCMBuffer using Accelerate framework in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891012/spectrogram-from-avaudiopcmbuffer-using-accelerate-framework-in-swift)

Although, the magnitudes from '*spectrum*' are either '*0*', '*inf*' or '*nan*', and the '*real*' and '*imag*' components of the complex split print similar results; indicating that this is the cause of the problem as: '*magnitude = sqrt(pow(**real**,2)+pow(**imag**,2)*'. Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think the rest of the code is ok.

**Why am I receiving these results and how can I fix it (what should the split components be), and what am I doing wrong?** Please keep in mind that I am very new to FFT and sampling and haven't got a clue how to set this up for an audio file, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code i'm using:

```
    // get audio file
    let fileURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("foo", withExtension: "mp3")!
    let audioFile = try!  AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)
    let fileFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
    let frameCount = UInt32(audioFile.length)

    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: fileFormat, frameCapacity: frameCount)
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    audioMixerNode = audioEngine.mainMixerNode

    let bufferSize = Int(frameCount)
    let channels: NSArray = [Int(buffer.format.channelCount)]
    let channelCount = channels.count
    let floats1 = [Int(buffer.frameLength)]
    for var i=0; i<channelCount; ++i {
        channelSamples.append([])
        let firstSample = buffer.format.interleaved ? i : i*bufferSize
        for var j=firstSample; j<bufferSize; j+=buffer.stride*2 {
            channelSamples[i].append(DSPComplex(real: buffer.floatChannelData.memory[j], imag: buffer.floatChannelData.memory[j+buffer.stride]))
        }
    }

    // connect node
    audioEngine.attachNode(playerNode)
    audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioMixerNode, format: playerNode.outputFormatForBus(0))

    // Set up the transform
    let log2n = UInt(round(log2(Double(bufferSize))))
    let fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, Int32(kFFTRadix2))

    // Create the complex split value to hold the output of the transform
    // why doesn't this work?
    var realp = [Float](count: bufferSize/2, repeatedValue: 0)
    var imagp = [Float](count: bufferSize/2, repeatedValue: 0)
    var output = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &realp, imagp: &imagp)

    vDSP_ctoz(UnsafePointer(channelSamples), 2, &output, 1, UInt(bufferSize / 2))

    // Do the fast Fourier forward transform
    vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &output, 1, log2n, Int32(FFT_FORWARD))

    // Convert the complex output to magnitude
    var fft = [Float](count:Int(bufferSize / 2), repeatedValue:0.0)
    let bufferOver2: vDSP_Length = vDSP_Length(bufferSize / 2)
    vDSP_zvmags(&output, 1, &fft, 1, bufferOver2)

    var spectrum = [Float]()
    for var i=0; i<bufferSize/2; ++i {
        let imag = output.imagp[i]
        let real = output.realp[i]
        let magnitude = sqrt(pow(real,2)+pow(imag,2))
        spectrum.append(magnitude) }

    // Release the setup
    vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(fftSetup)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with your code:

1. you weren't reading in the audio file samples
2. channelSamples was packed incorrectly
3. `vDSP_fft_zrip` was reading beyond the end of the array. it expects 2^log2n samples
4. `vDSP_fft_zrip`'s output is [packed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH202-15947) and your calculations expect unpacked

**Swift 4 version now with actual fix for point 3**

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foo", withExtension: "mp3")!
let audioFile = try!  AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL as URL)
let frameCount = UInt32(audioFile.length)

let log2n = UInt(round(log2(Double(frameCount))))
let bufferSizePOT = Int(1 << log2n)

let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFile.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSizePOT))!
try! audioFile.read(into: buffer, frameCount:frameCount)

// Not sure if AVAudioPCMBuffer zero initialises extra frames, so when in doubt...
let leftFrames = buffer.floatChannelData![0]
for i in Int(frameCount)..<Int(bufferSizePOT) {
    leftFrames[i] = 0
}

// Set up the transform
let fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, Int32(kFFTRadix2))!

// create packed real input
var realp = [Float](repeating: 0, count: bufferSizePOT/2)
var imagp = [Float](repeating: 0, count: bufferSizePOT/2)
var output = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &realp, imagp: &imagp)

leftFrames.withMemoryRebound(to: DSPComplex.self, capacity: bufferSizePOT / 2) {
    vDSP_ctoz($0, 2, &output, 1, UInt(bufferSizePOT / 2))
}

// Do the fast Fourier forward transform, packed input to packed output
vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &output, 1, log2n, Int32(FFT_FORWARD))

// you can calculate magnitude squared here, with care
// as the first result is wrong! read up on packed formats
var fft = [Float](repeating:0.0, count:Int(bufferSizePOT / 2))
vDSP_zvmags(&output, 1, &fft, 1, vDSP_Length(bufferSizePOT / 2))

// Release the setup
vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(fftSetup)
```

Comment: Can you help with making this work on Swift 4.0+  , i have done the conversion, as aside from the vDSP_ctoz everything was automatic, however the output results are not as expected.

Comment: all of the values are nan, still tinkering with it.

Comment: ouch, that code references beyond the end of the `AVAudioPCMBuffer`'s memory. maybe I'll replace this answer with the fixed swift 4 version.

Comment: Awesome, missed it. Thanks a ton!